# Adjacency list representation of graph is not printing adjacent nodes. Why?

Tags: c

In this adjacency list program, the nodes adjacent are not getting displayed properly.
There could be a mistake in the insert function or in the `display` function. Each node has an edge list but the edge list isn't printed while displaying the graph. It could have an error somewhere.
I don't know where is it. It could be a semantic error.

//implementation of adjacency list representation

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define maxnodes 50

typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *link;    
}graph;

//inserting edge list for each node
void insert_node(graph **node_p,int i,int j)
{
    graph *temp;
    temp=(graph *)malloc(sizeof(graph));
    temp->data=j;
    temp->link=node_p[j];
    node_p[j]=temp;
}

void create_graph(graph **nodep)
{
    int i,j;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("enter source and destination nodes");
        scanf("%d %d",&i,&j);
        if(i==0 && j==0)
            break;
        insert_node(nodep,i,j);   
    }
}

void display(graph **nodep,int n)
{
    int i;
    graph *cur;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        cur=nodep[i];
        printf("\n the nodes adjacent to node %d are=",i);
        while(cur!=NULL)
        {
          printf("\t%d",cur->data); 
          cur=cur->link; 
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    int n,ch;
    graph *nodelist[maxnodes];
    printf("enter number of number of nodes in the graph");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        nodelist[i]=NULL;

    while(1)
    {
        printf("\nenter option 1.create graph 2.display 3.exit");
        scanf("%d",&ch);
        switch(ch)
        {
           case 1:create_graph(nodelist);
                  break;
           case 2:display(nodelist,n);
                  break;
           case 3:exit(0); 
                   break; 
          default:
                 break;
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Indentation *please*. It makes code *much* easier to read if you have consistent indentation (and consistent coding-style in general, for example for curly-braces placement).

Comment: As for your problems, have you tried to step through the code statement by statement in a debugger?

Comment: You're never using the parameter `i` in `insert_node`.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data, with the expected and actual output from that data.  That's an important part of creating an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).

Comment: The loop in `main()` where you have `for(i=1;i<=n;i++) nodelist[i]=NULL;` is not idiomatic C.  Loops in C normally run `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)`.  You also do not check that `n` is strictly less than `maxnodes` before using it.

Comment: You do not tell `create_graph()` how many nodes there are, nor do you validate that the entered node numbers are both valid, nor that `scanf()` reads two values, nor that the two node numbers are different.  These are problems that should be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic inside your `insert_node()` function is completely wrong.

Assuming, you are building an undirected graph, if the user enters the pair `i, j`, you have to push node `i` to the adjacency list of `j` and also node `j` to that of node `i`.

Another major mistake is, you are always appending the newly created node, which you denote by `temp` to the first element of the adjacency list of the other node, which is true only in case the other node's neighbors' list was empty. You first have to check `if(node_p[i] == NULL)`. If that is true, you can directly append the `temp` to that `node_p[i]`, otherwise you have to follow `link`s to get to the last element of the adjacency list and append `temp` there.

The modified code looks like this

```c
void insert_node(graph **node_p,int i,int j)
    {
        /* Add j to adj list of i */
        graph *temp;
        temp=(graph *)malloc(sizeof(graph));
        temp->data=j;
        temp->link=NULL;

        if(node_p[i] == NULL) /* First Node */
            node_p[i]=temp;
        else
        {
            graph *loc;
            loc = node_p[i];
            while(loc->link != NULL)
                loc = loc->link;
            loc->link = temp;
        }
        
        /*** COMMENT THIS PORTION IF THE GRAPH IS DIRECTED ***/
        /* Add i to adj list of j */
        graph *temp1;
        temp1 = (graph *)malloc(sizeof(graph));
        temp1->data = i;
        temp1->link = NULL;

        if(node_p[j] == NULL) /* First Node */
            node_p[j]=temp1;
        else
        {
            graph *loc;
            loc = node_p[j];
            while(loc->link != NULL)
                loc = loc->link;
            loc->link = temp1;
        }
    }
```

In case you are building a directed graph i.e, `i -> j` and not `j -> i`, comment out the second half of the code that says `/* Add i to adj list of j */`.

Using this. I got this output on the following graph of 5 nodes whose edges are = `{1-2, 1-5, 1-3, 2-4}`

```
enter number of number of nodes in the graph5

enter option 1.create graph 2.display 3.exit 1
enter source and destination nodes 1 2
enter source and destination nodes 1 5
enter source and destination nodes 1 3
enter source and destination nodes 2 4
enter source and destination nodes 0 0

enter option 1.create graph 2.display 3.exit 2

 the nodes adjacent to node 1 are=  2   5   3
 the nodes adjacent to node 2 are=  1   4
 the nodes adjacent to node 3 are=  1
 the nodes adjacent to node 4 are=  2
 the nodes adjacent to node 5 are=  1
enter option 1.create graph 2.display 3.exit3
```

Comment: Surely the duplicated code inside `insert_node()` should be factored out into a function called twice.  I'd be inclined to keep one half of the code and call `insert_node(nodep, i, j); insert_node(nodep, j, i);` in `create_graph()`.

Comment: Yes sure, but I was not clear about OP's intentions regarding directed or undirected graph, so I left it that way. I just wanted to point out why the code was not working in the first place.

Comment: Your code enforces an undirected graph — it doesn't look as if you were very unclear.  It would be easier to document `/* omit this call if the graph is directed */` before the second call to `insert_node()` in my proposed solution.